# How can I create container in azurite running from test container in java?

Tags: azure, docker, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5, azurite

I am trying to test azure file upload using azurite docker image from test container below is code I am using for the same

```java
public class AzureContainer {

    public static AzureContainer INSTANCE = new AzureContainer();

    private static final String connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://0.0.0.0:10000/devstoreaccount1";

    private AzureContainer(){
        GenericContainer<?> azureContainer = new GenericContainer<>
                ("mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite")
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(
                new HostConfig().withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(10000),
                        new ExposedPort(10000)))
        ));
        azureContainer.start();
    }

    public String getConnectionString() {
        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can create container while starting the container itself? If I got and create container manually it is working fine but problem is when I am running code from CI/CD pipeline I can't create container manually.

Comment: Can you give more details about the context of your tests? The code you shared will create a container and start it. It is however very unusual to call `start()` in the constructor. Usually, you would extend `GenericContainer` and then call `start()` as part of your tests.

Comment: Hi @KevinWittek thanks for the reply the context of test is i need to upload a file to azure blob container as part of one of the function in my code. I am not extending the Generic Container because i am already extending other class because of which i am start container in constructor. If i am running the test cases individually it is working fine but when i run the test cases using jacoco it is giving following error Exception while uploading file into BlobStorage com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: An unknown failure occurred : Unexpected end of file from server

Comment: I meant I need the context of your code, so I understand how you interact with TC. Since starting the container from the constructor is not something we normally do, I suspect it could be related about this. What happens if you run the whole test suite, but without Jabcoco? Does it also fail?

Comment: Hi @KevinWittek without jacoco if i am running individual test cases it is running fine

Comment: Can you please run without jacoco, but the whole test suite?